# Upload field with custom form requiring a custom implementation of Field()

Tags: php, upload, silverstripe

I have some custom routes in my system:

```
---
Name: mysiteroutes
---
Director:
  rules:
    'create//$Action': 'CreateController'
```

Which has a custom controller to create a form:

```
class CreateController extends Page_Controller{

    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'submit'
    );

    public function link($action = null) {
        return $this->join_links('create/', $action);
    }

    public function index() {
        $form = Form::create(
            $this,
            '',
            FieldList::create(
                TextField::create('Name', 'Name'),
                $upload = new UploadField('Upload', 'Upload')
            ),
            FieldList::create(
                FormAction::create('submit', 'Submit')->setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-success')
            ),
            RequiredFields::create('Name')
        );
        if($this->request->isPost()) return $form;
        return $this->customise(array('Form'=>$form))->renderWith(array("Create", "Page"));     
    }

    public function submit($data, $form = null) {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->params();
        var_dump($params);
    }
}
```

When I try and upload something it calls `Field()` on my controller and then fails as it's not there. I can add it and it calls it correctly however I have no idea what to put in it. I've looked through the `Field()` function in `UploadField.php` however there is a lot of code there which I probably shouldn't just copy.

How should I manage the upload of the file in my custom controller or can I forward it to the core framework somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UploadField expects to have a route based on the Form name, in your case `''`.
If you would change the name of the form to `form` it would call `form/field/Upload/upload`. What this does is get the `form`, then get the `field` with the name `Upload` and call the method `upload` on that class.

Unfortunately, the way you are using the form (which I showed you in an earlier answer :( ) does not support this.

We could solve it like this;

**CreateController**

```
class CreateController extends Page_Controller
{
    private static $allowed_actions = [
        'form'
    ];

    public function link($action = null) 
    {
        return $this->join_links('create', $action);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->renderWith(array("Create", "Page"));     
    }

    public function form()
    {
        return UploadForm::create($this, 'form', 'submit');
    }

    public function submit($data, $form = null)
    {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->params();
        var_dump($params);
    }
}
```

**Form**

```
// create an extra class for the form to keep your controller clean
class UploadForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($controller, $name, $action)
    {
        $fields = FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('Name', 'Name'),
            UploadField::create('Upload', 'Upload')
        );

        $actions = FieldList::create(
            FormAction::create($action, 'Submit')
                ->setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-success')
        );

        $validator = RequiredFields::create('Name');

        parent::__construct($controller, $name, $fields, $actions, $validator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for you answering all my questions. There isn't much detail about custom routing with forms, or with SilverStripe in general which is a shame because it's a great framework.

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help. Was this answer helpfull for you?

Comment: It's at work so I'll have to test later, I'm sure it will be but have to check.

Comment: One thing I'm lost with, how does the template know to render the `form()`? Is it because the template has $Form it looks for a function called `form` in the parent controller?

Comment: That's because we return `$this` (the controller) in the index method. Because a Controller is also an instance of `ViewableData`, all the methods on the controller are available in the template. Note that when you call `$this->customise(array('Form' => $form))`, only the `$Form` is available in the template.